# Does this system of PDEs always have a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following system of PDEs for a function $u:\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$:
\begin{align}
&\partial_x u(x,y) = F(u(x,y),x); \tag{1}\\
&\partial_y u(x,y) \neq 0 \tag{2}.
\end{align}
where $F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is some function. My question is basically the following:

**Given that $F$ is, say, $C^\infty$, does this system of PDEs always have a $C^\infty$ solution?**

Note that if we fix $y=y_0$, then the first equations is an ODE $\partial_x u = F(u,x)$, so if $F$ is $C^\infty$ then $F$ in particular satisfies the conditions of the Picard-Lindelof theorem, and this equation locally has a unique solution, for each individual value of $y_0$, if we provide an initial value $u(x_0,y_0)=u_0$ for each $y_0$.

The next step I have in mind is that possibly, given initial data $u(x_0,y)=f(y)$, say with $f$ a $C^\infty$ function, we will have locally a unique solution to $(1)$. The difficulty here, I guess, is that all the domains of the solutions for fixed $y$ should intersect to a nonempty domain.

And then finally the question is wether we can choose the initial data $f$ in such a way that equation $(2)$ will be satisfied.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please specify where are the initial conditions? On the semi-axis $\{x>0,y=0\}\cup \{y>0,x=0\}$? Or on $\partial \Omega$? If it is the latter do you have any assumption on the regularity of $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: @TommasoSeneci Initial conditions on the system (1), (2), are not specified. I'm just wondering if the system of equations has a solution.

Comment: So you want to find a function that exists in the whole $\Omega$ (fixed a priori) and satisfies this condition?

Comment: @TommasoSenici Oh good point, yes $/Omega$ is fixed a priory and in principle I want a solution on this (say open) set. If that might not be possible I would also be happy to find a solution on an open subset of $/Omega$.

Comment: It might look stupid, but if you fix, say, $u_y = 1$ then it is $\neq 0$ and so you have local solution thanks to Picard–Lindelöf theorem. This proves that you surely have solutions, tons of them;)

Comment: In don't see how the theorem is applicable, as the equations involve partial derivatives w.r.t. more then one variable.

Comment: You are right. What do you think about considering $y=y(x)$ and then solve for the ODE
$$ u'(x) = u'(x,y(x))=u_x(x,y(x))+u_y(x,y(x))y'(x) = F(u(x,y(x)),x)+u_y(x,y(x))y'(x). $$
For instance, in the case $y(x)=x$ you get
$$ u'(x) = F(u(x),x)+u_y(x,x), $$
whatever $u_y$ is, and here you can find a local solution by Picard. Let's continue to talk about that in chat without making this comments too long.